# What is an XmlNode?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I am trying to submit data to a web service using PHP and nusoap.  The web service operation I'm calling is located here: http://service.leads360.com/ClientService.asmx?op=AddLeads

The operation's expected parameters are `username` as string, `password` as string, and `leads` as XmlNode.  For this XmlNode they give examples of the schema and xml doc:

http://service.leads360.com/Documentation/Schemas/Client/Leads.Request.xsd

http://service.leads360.com/Documentation/Examples/Client/AddLeads.leads.xml

So I copied the xml doc they gave and turned it into an array, put that array inside another array called `$params` along with `username` and `password` and executed

```
$result = $client->call('AddLeads', $params);
```

Unfortunately it is giving me the following error:

```
[faultcode] => soap:Server
    [faultstring] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LeadManager.Business.XmlHelper.RemoveNamespace(XmlNode xml, Boolean asElement) in c:\Code\DEV\LeadManager_Business\Utilities\XmlHelper.cs:line 323
   at LeadManagerService.ClientService.InsertSerializedLeads(XmlNode descriptors)
   at LeadManagerService.ClientService.InsertLeads(XmlNode descriptor)
   at LeadManagerService.Invoker 1.Invoke(ServiceContext context, String methodName, ICredentials credentials, Object parameters, Requestor requestor)
   at LeadManagerService.ClientService.AddLeads(String username, String password, XmlNode leads)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I pasted my code at: http://pastebin.com/7jbPGuqn.

I am also pasting the array I am passing as the leads parameter below.  Please tell me if the array represents the xml doc in the example and if it is a valid `XmlNode`.

```
Array
(
    [Leads] => Array
        (
            [Lead] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Status] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [Status_attr] => Array
                                (
                                    [StatusId] => 2
                                )
                            [Campaign] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [Campaign_attr] => Array
                                (
                                    [CampaignId] => 3
                                )
                            [Agent] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [Agent_attr] => Array
                                (
                                    [AgentId] => 1
                                )
                            [Fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [Field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [0_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 2
                                                    [Value] => F1Name
                                                )
                                            [1_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 3
                                                    [Value] => L1Name
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [2_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 4
                                                    [Value] => a@y.com
                                                )
                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [3_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 5
                                                    [Value] => 111111111
                                                )
                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [4_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 6
                                                    [Value] => 
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [Field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [0_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 2
                                                    [Value] => F2Name
                                                )
                                            [1_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 3
                                                    [Value] => L2Name
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [2_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 4
                                                    [Value] => b@y.com
                                                )
                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [3_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 5
                                                    [Value] => 222222222
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [Field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [0_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 2
                                                    [Value] => F3Name
                                                )
                                            [1_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 3
                                                    [Value] => L3Name
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [2_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => 4
                                                    [Value] => c@y.com
                                                )
                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [3_attr] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldId] => -9999999
                                                    [Value] => 333333333
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an element who's value is something simple as an int or string, an `XmlNode` is a more complex structure, it is an XML element.

Inside the WSDL of the service you will find the following for the `AddLeads` element:

```
<s:element name="AddLeads">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="leads">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any/>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

This is the schema for the `AddLeads` element. The schema will be used to validate the markup you provide.

Notice that `username` and `password` have the type string, while `leads` is "any" complex type. That will mean a message like this one:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <AddLeads>
     <username>foo</username>
     <password>bar</password>
     <leads>
        You may enter ANY elements at this point
     </leads>
  </AddLeads>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But "any" complex type is a little bit to wide as a definition, so the creators of the web service decided to limit it to something they recognize as useful information. The following schema limits the "any" in the context of the `AddLeads` operation:

http://service.leads360.com/Documentation/Schemas/Client/Leads.Request.xsd

for which the following is a valid instance:

http://service.leads360.com/Documentation/Examples/Client/AddLeads.leads.xml

I don't know PHP but your code must generate a message that respects the web service WSDL types an the `leads` type.

I suggest you use a tool like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to create requests to call the web service. Once you get a valid message content with a successful response, adapt your PHP code to generate the same format. You will also find (another tool) the [TCP Monitor](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) very useful in seeing what messages get exchanged between your client and the web service.